# perserve user search options in php

Tags: php

I am working on PHP application.i have a search from in which user can select  many options to refine his search like month,year,group,departement etc.

Now user submits the forms and gets the results based on his search options.User navigates to other forms in the application.When user comes back to search page i need top present him the old search options.

Please share your thoughts on it

Comment: Store the search in a session variable and filter on that

Comment: read about sessions/cookies/or store into database ..

Answer (score 2):

The common way to do this is to use `$_SESSION`.

For every search he makes save all his options in session, then later apply what he selected to your form.

eg:

```
foreach($department as $key => $val){
    $selected = '';
    if($key == $_SESSION['department']){
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$val.'</option>';
}
```

after he submit the form you set that session:

```
$_SESSION['department'] = $_POST['department'];
```

Comment: since you want your customer/user to be able to navigate to your website and be able to return to your search results page with preloaded his preferences, I would suggest to use sessions, cookies or database to store his search criteria.

Comment: he can use all of them sessions, cookies and database for a nice impact on client :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `session` to store the search query.

Whenever you change the search criteria change the search query in the `session`.

But this is not a good practice as per your requirement this is the best solution.

One more thing is you can append the search criteria to the URL this is the best and preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session or cookies to do so.
When you are submitting the form, just store the data within session or cookies, and when the form is building up, just check if the session value exists. If exists, just put the value of the element in respective form element(textbox, textarea etc.).

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if((isset($_SESSION['location'])) && ($_SESSION['location'] != '')) echo $_SESSION['location']; ?>" name="location" />
```

So, when a user re-navigate after a search, will be able to see his/ her search values, as they will come on form fields.